# Find-Object networking with rasperry pi board picamera

Tags: computer-vision

I'm trying to get the Find-Object application from ( http://introlab.github.io/find-object/ ) to capture video being sent across my wifi network from my raspberry 4 board. That RPI board is using it's picamera in a python script.

But ... the Find-Object crashes when I run my python script on the RPI board .
It prints an error message , something about Qt exception ...and immediatly closes on the laptop.
Unfortunatly I cannot provide details of the error message because the Find_Object app quickly closes.

I'm using a simple TCP socket client script on the RPI, written in python and that uses the network iP address of my laptop as assigned by my router, e.g. 192.168.x.y ( NOT the ip address displayed by the app when it is running and waiting listening;- 169.254.157.36 )
I'm setting the port values to the same value on both ends.

Has anyone managed to get Find-Object to capture and display video across a network from a raspberry pi board ?

How ?  What setting did you use ?

thanks
agribot

Comment: Run the Qt app from a terminal window. This should then show any error messages. Because you say it's running on a laptop I assume it's not a Pi (?). If that's the case why do you think it's a Pi related problem?

Comment: Thanks Dirk for your comment. Yes, Find-Object is running on my Dell laptop, with Windows 10 OS.  Find-Object make no mention of a need to install Qt. The problem is that I cannot get Find-Object to use a video stream coming across my wifi network from my Raspberry pi. So perhaps the fault is the settings / configuration of the client script running on the RPI 4 board ? Has anyone managed to get Find-Object to capture video via a network, from a TCP socket interface ?